# Number of local minimums and nonconvexity

Tags: convex-analysis

I came across the following in my reading, and I like to know why this is true.

"$\dots$ but, the fuction $F:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb {R}$ is nonconvex since it has several local minima $\dots$"

What does the number of local minima have to do with convexity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually possible for a convex function to have multiple local minima, but the set of local minima must in that case *form a convex set*, and they must all have the same value. So, for instance, the convex function $f(x)=\max\{\|x\|-1,0\}$ has a minimum of $0$ for all $\|x\|\leq 1$. (In one dimension, a convex set is just an interval.)

In particular, what is *not* possible is for a convex function to have multiple *disjoint* local minima. For instance, the nonconvex function $f(x)=(x^2-1)^2$ obtains a minimum of $0$ when $x=\pm 1$.

Consider also the nonconvex function in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f(x)=(\|x\|^2-1)^2$. This function obtains a minimum of $0$ when $\|x\|=1$, the unit ball. This optimal set is connected when $n\geq 2$, but not convex.

Of course, a convex function need not have a minimum at all; for instance $f(x)=e^x$. But *if* a convex function has a local minimum, it is a global minimum, and this and all other points that achieve this same value form a convex set.

Comment: The reason why it it not possible to have multiple disjoint local minima  is because a convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected?

Comment: That's right. The set of points that achieve the minimum value of a convex function *must* form a convex set, and convex sets are connected.

Comment: What is the idea behind that the set of minimizers of a convex function necessarily forms a convex set?

Comment: I'm not sure what to say here. It is simply a consequence of the definition of convexity. It's not just the set of minimizers, either. *All* sub-level sets $\{x\,|\,f(x)\leq a\}$, where $f$ is a convex function and $a$ is a constant, are convex. That is a necessary but not sufficient condition for convexity. So if $a=\min_x f(x)$, you have the above result.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed a convex function can only have one local max (which is therefore a global max).  Think about this in the case $n=1$.  Draw a smooth function with two local maxima and you'll see there has to be an inflection point where it goes from convex to concave.

Comment: This can be adapted to higher dimensions.  Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be two local minima (in $\mathbb{R}^n$).  Then, consider the restriction of the function to the line containing these two points.  The restriction of a local min is a local min, and the restriction of a convex function is convex.  Then, Gregory's comment applies.

Comment: What if two local minima give the same minimum value? i.e. $f(x_1)=f(x_2)?$

Comment: Well conceivably the function could become constant at some point, but if there are only finitely many local minima then it would have to change inflection between them.  One could argue a constant function has many local minima (ever point is a minimum) but it is still convex (as well as concave) (I think)

Comment: Slight correction: a convex function can only have one local *minima*.